# Delete all character after particular character in string

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have a string and I want to delete some character after particulate character, I tried using with substring but nothings working

Comment: Can you show the code you tried so we can tell you where you went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"word" is a String Variable here where you can apply your needs and "T" is a character after which you want to delete all other characters

```
if let index = word.range(of: "T")?.lowerBound {
                let substring = word[..<index]
                let string = String(substring)
                self.birthdayField.text = string
            }
```

Comment: Why no simply `string.firstIndex(of: Character)`?